# Multiple image upload PHP, loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to upload multiple images to my server, I have the following that works if uploading a single image, only im unsure where I go next?

I have a POST form that submits 3 images, the following only uploads the first, will I need to create a while loop for each image?

So far Ive written...

```
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . date('U')."-".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);  // add a unique string to the uploaded filename so that it is unique.
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . date('U')."-".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";

}
```

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

Comment: Do **NOT** use this script. You have multiple serious "please take over my server" vulnerabilities in it.

Comment: @MarcB It would be helpful to elaborate!

Comment: Relying on MIME types can be dangerous because its easy to spoof them by creating hybrid files (header part takes care of identification, the rest of the file is malicious) however aside from that I don't see anything more serious. Care to elaborate MarcB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549454/what-are-the-flaws-one-must-care-in-file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your script you can do it by:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
 $aFile = $_FILES['file'][$i];

 // your code ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] should be addressed like $aFile['tmp_name'] and so on..
}
```

Comment: Yes, you loop through the array of `$_FILES`. When you upload one file per request you can address it by `$_FILES['dom_name']['name']`, when you upload multiple files you can address them like `$_FILES['dom_name'][0]['name']`, `$_FILES['dom_name'][1]['name']` etc.